# window location get the URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have code witch get cornet url
in url i want add foloder/  and i get link =   hostname/folder/pathname

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="Link" href="#">open link</a> 
    <script> 
      $(document).ready(function(){
       var newURL = window.location.hostname + "folder/" + window.location.pathname; 
       $("#Link").attr("href", newURL);  
      });
    </script>
```

this code but did not works

Comment: Change `"folder/"` to `/"folder"`. `window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname + "/folder" + window.location.pathname;`

Comment: it help but have other problem

Comment: /js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_loc_href     this curnet link  and  i get   only /js/tryit.asp    (window.location.pathname this works incocet didnot show full link)

Comment: Add `+window.location.search` at last.